# Nested ng-repeat in the same array level

Tags: jquery, angularjs

How can I add a "div" after every each 3 repetitions?

### This is my array:

```
[
   client : "name",
   client : "name",
   client : "name",
   client : "name",
   client : "name",
   client : "name",
   client : "name",
   client : "name",
   client : "name",

]
```

The result expected is:

```
<div>name</div>
<div>name</div>
<div>name</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div>name</div>
<div>name</div>
<div>name</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div>name</div>
<div>name</div>
<div>name</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: is it an array or json?

Comment: You can use the ng-switch directive with the $index value of the ng-repeat to display different separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a filter that splits your array in groups of three and nest the groups.

The filter should be something like this:

```js
app.filter('split', function() {
  return function(target) {
    var splitted = [];

    if (!target) {
      return target;
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < target.length; i += 3) {
      splitted.push(target.slice(i, i+3));
    }

    return splitted;
 }
});
```

In your controller, just initialize:

```js
$scope.original = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```

Finally, this is how your HTML should be:

```html
<div ng-repeat="group in original | split">
  <div ng-repeat="item in group">{{item}}</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

You can parametrize the group length. This can be achieved by adding a second param to the filter and passing `ng-repeat="group in original | split:3"`.

Not that the original array is not modified. Here is a [working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MMk8GN?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

Why not split your initial array ?

```
[
    [
        client : "name",
        client : "name",
        client : "name"
    ],
    [
        client : "name",
        client : "name",
        client : "name"
    ],
    [
        client : "name",
        client : "name",
        client : "name"
    ]
]
```

Comment: Because I cant change the API :) Good thinking but I really need the array untouched.

Comment: I am searching something more like this, but don't know the correct way of using it and also cant make it work with my structure -> http://jsfiddle.net/4LhN9/46/

Comment: What cannot you change in your API ?
If you get an array from your API, you still can modify it before to send it to your view, cannot you ?

Comment: I am receving all the clients form a Standard web api external to my power of chaging it.

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this can be to use the `$index` angular variable inside the loop as in this plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/ycnPtBLmbtV8hwIFTsGd?p=preview

Moreover, the data you have posted is not a valid array or valid json. i'm assuming that you are having to deal with json. If you meant an array, the same `$index` method can be used for the array also.

Comment: I think CaioToOn solution is better becouse I don't want to start have coustom code in  the HTML files, would you agree with this?

Comment: Actually, this solution is also quite good. The only downside I see is that the you will have many elements in DOM that will never be shown, and they watches will run in every `$apply` cycle for nothing (although they're simple). You could change the `ng-show` for [`ui-if`](http://angular-ui.github.io/#directives-if). But then you would get some extra kbs, dependencies and still the watches and some extra compilation. I'd stick with the filter.

Answer (score -1):

Can you just loop through the array, check if that iteration is divisible by three and insert the extra div?

Comment: Ask questions bellow my question. This place is for answers.